# SQL Developer: Procedure To Insert In A table New Records from Another One

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm triying to figure out how to insert records stored in the #TableA (STAGE_REMEDY) that does not exist in the #TableB (HIST_REMEDY). Comparing each other using the Date (FECHA_ENVIO field in my case), just to validate that I'd be inserting just NEW data and agrouping in the right way.

I'm using SQL Developer and I've tried to develop different procedures to reach my objective. My code below shows my tried that in fact does not work (Doesn't insert data in the table i don't know why). Also, I'm using SUBSTR , cause' the field has the date in the format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

```
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO HIST_REMEDY (HORA_ENVIO, HORA_RESOLUCION,
    TIEMPO_SLA_MINUTOS, GRUPO_ASIGNADO,INCIDENCIA,CUENTA,
    RESUMEN,COMENTARIOS,ESTADO,
    FECHA_ENVIO,FECHA_RESOLUCION,FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION,
    USUARIO_ASIGNADO,REGION,CIUDAD,RESOLN1,RESOLN2,RESOLN3,
    CN,NO_ACTIVIDAD,
    OS,DEPARTAMENTO,ORGANIZACION,AREA,USUARIOR,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,GRUPO_ASIGNADO_MDA,AREA_ESCALA,
    CATEGORIA_SLA,MAL_GENERADO,
    USR_SIEBEL,NOMBRE_CLAVE,
    AREA_PROVENIENTE,RECURRENTE,
    ESCALADO,SEVERIDAD, SERVICIO)
SELECT HORA_ENVIO, HORA_RESOLUCION,
    TIEMPO_SLA_MINUTOS, GRUPO_ASIGNADO,INCIDENCIA,CUENTA,
    RESUMEN,COMENTARIOS,ESTADO,
    FECHA_ENVIO,FECHA_RESOLUCION,FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION,
    USUARIO_ASIGNADO,REGION,CIUDAD,RESOLN1,RESOLN2,RESOLN3,
    CN,NO_ACTIVIDAD,
    OS,DEPARTAMENTO,ORGANIZACION,AREA,USUARIOR,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,GRUPO_ASIGNADO_MDA,AREA_ESCALA,
    CATEGORIA_SLA,MAL_GENERADO,
    USR_SIEBEL,NOMBRE_CLAVE,
    AREA_PROVENIENTE,RECURRENTE,
    ESCALADO,SEVERIDAD, SERVICIO
FROM STAGE_REMEDY
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HIST_REMEDY WHERE SUBSTR (HIST_REMEDY.FECHA_ENVIO,0,10) = SUBSTR (STAGE_REMEDY.FECHA_ENVIO,0,10))
GROUP BY HORA_ENVIO, HORA_RESOLUCION,
    TIEMPO_SLA_MINUTOS, GRUPO_ASIGNADO,INCIDENCIA,CUENTA,
    RESUMEN,COMENTARIOS,ESTADO,
    FECHA_ENVIO,FECHA_RESOLUCION,FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION,
    USUARIO_ASIGNADO,REGION,CIUDAD,RESOLN1,RESOLN2,RESOLN3,
    CN,NO_ACTIVIDAD,
    OS,DEPARTAMENTO,ORGANIZACION,AREA,USUARIOR,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,GRUPO_ASIGNADO_MDA,AREA_ESCALA,
    CATEGORIA_SLA,MAL_GENERADO,
    USR_SIEBEL,NOMBRE_CLAVE,
    AREA_PROVENIENTE,RECURRENTE,
    ESCALADO,SEVERIDAD, SERVICIO;
COMMIT;
END;
```

My expectations is get a database where I can store all the new data gets on the #TableA (STAGE_REMEDY).

Regards!

Comment: The use of NOT EXISTS means that if you have 30000 records in STAGE_REMEDY where `trunc(FECHA_ENVIO) = date '2019-05-07'` and **one** record in HIST_REMEDY where `trunc(FECHA_ENVIO) = date '2019-05-07'` no records would be inserted. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: @APC Exactly! I'm triying to insert new data from STARE_REMEDY table to HIST_REMEDY table. Validating that the data does not exist on HIST_REMEDY based on FECHA_ENVIO

Comment: Did you want to match all fields of TABLE1 with TABLE2? Or matching FECHA_ENVIO will work.